# ternary operator || Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`3' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, argb

```
private void Disable_Proxy_textboxes(bool v)
{
    v = !v;
    address_textbox.Enabled = v;
    port_textbox.Enabled = v;
    port_label.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(v?(255,255,255):(100, 100, 100));
    address_label.ForeColor=v?(Color.FromArgb(255,255,255)):(Color.FromArgb(100,100,100));
}
```

While coding I decided to play around the ternary operators and now am really confused why there is an error in `port_label.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(v?(255,255,255):(100, 100, 100));`. I understand that the next line is very correct but why does this specific line show the following errors:

```
Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`3' is not defined or imported
cannot convert from '(int, int, int)' to 'int'
```

The docs just say

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

So are both the data types not the same in my case?  Are both the cases not same as this example?

```
bool c=a?true:false;
a?(c=true):(c=false);
```

What is it that I am not understanding. Also please this is not one of those *why is this code not working*, I am not asking any debugging here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the conditional operator, both sides are of type `` ValueTuple`3 ``. So the conditional operator `?` returns a `` ValueTuple`3 ``.

But no overload of [`Color.FromArgb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb) takes a `` ValueTuple`3 `` as argument.

The compiler does not deconstruct the `` ValueTuple`3 `` into the three `int` arguments for the overload you intend to use.

Comment: All right I get it. `Color.FromArgb` does not accept a value of the type `ValueTuple\`3`  as `Color.FromArgb=ValueTuple\`3` is totally invalid. It takes a `ValueTuple\`3` as a parameter and this there is an error in the line but not in the next line. Did i get it right? A beginner.

Comment: @Rishav yes, in the next line your conditional operator returns a `Color` (because both sides call `Color.FromArgb()`) and this is assigned to `ForeColor`. In the first line you try to call `FromArgb()` with a ``ValueTuple`3``, which causes the error.